# cosmosdb mongo api execute stored function from c# client

Tags: c#, mongodb

**Server**:        cosmosdb mongo api 
**Clinet**:        C#
**Client Driver**: [MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver)

Hi,

I have created user defined function / stored function (system.js function) in cosmosdb and I can able to execute it from ROBO 3T 1.1.1. When I tried to execute it from C#, I received the error

> command is not supported.

```
var cmd = db.RunCommand(new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("$eval", "echoFunction(3);")));
```

But the same is working fine in mongodb server.

Thanks

Comment: Did you verify while debugging that you have connection to the correct db?

Comment: yes. connected to the correct db. I execute the command var mongoDatabaseStatsResult = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("dbstats", 1)); its working fine against cosmosdb. issue with only custom  functions.